# SAS Spllit a column into multiple

Tags: sas

I was wondering if there is a way to separate a column into 2 or more columns. The values are separated by semicolon.

Here is how my data is currently

```
+------------+
|    Col1    |
+------------+
| 541.6;I345 |
+------------+
```

I would like something as below

```
+--------+------+
|  Col1  | Col2 |
+--------+------+
| 541.6  | I345 |
+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try  **`scan`**:

```
data want;
set have;
col2 = scan(col1,2,";");
col1 = scan(col1,1,";");
run;
```

Let me know in case of any queries.

Comment: This will result in `col1` having a numeric value being stored in a character variable. If you want to convert `col1` from character to numeric some additional code is needed.

Comment: @user667489 Those look like Diagnosis codes which are often stored as characters.